# Shell script: get date as variable

Tags: shell

I am trying to create a quick script that will get a file from a backup folder. The backup file is generated every day and have the filename format of:

> backup-sql-YYYYMMDD.zip

I am trying to get the filename by using:

```
#!/bin/sh

VAR_1="backup-sql-"
VAR_2=date +%Y%m%d
VAR_3=$VAR_1$VAR_2

echo "$VAR_3"
```

However the output is:

> backup-sql-

When I run:

```
date +%Y%m%d
```

I get

```
20180704
```

So I am not sure why this is happening.  Please can someone help me :)

Comment: You are missing command substitution. Paste your code to [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: Your shell must be broken since it's not giving you a syntax error on `VAR_2=date +%Y%m%d` (assuming you'd have acted on it or at the very least told us about it if you were getting a syntax error).

Comment: @PesaThe Thank you - that helped and is a great tool. +1

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the reply, I solved it with the answer below by adding `$()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
$(command)
```

or

```
`command`
```

From your example give a try to:

```
VAR_2=$(date +%Y%m%d)
```

Check [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) for more details:

> When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash retains its literal meaning except when followed by ‘$’, ‘`’, or ‘\’. The first backquote not preceded by a backslash terminates the command substitution. When using the $(command) form, all characters between the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using backticks to capture the output of the date command and assign it to a shell variable.

```
VAR2=`date "+%Y%m%d"`
```

In case you want to make sure the variable value is passed on to subsequent child processes you may want to export it as:

```
export VAR2=`date "+%Y%m%d"`
```

Comment: No you should not be using backticks. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html